# How to extract company name from emails using find() method in python?

Tags: python

I'm still very new to Python. I'm working on my assignment but I still do not understand how the find() method work when extracting emails. The purpose of the function is to extract the company of the email (i.e., everything after the @ sign but before the .) using the find() method.

Example Usage:

extract_company("larhe@uber.com") should return "uber"

So I understand that find(subtr, start, end). And I know how it should work, but in only one condition. However, this asked to find the company name in between @ and .

This is the code I have been working so far but it still gives me an assertionerror

```py
def extract_company(email):
    return email.find('@' and '.')
```

Answer (score 2):

find() method find for the particular string etc. What you are looking for is the word after @ and before .com, so you can use regex for that. However there is another geeky method using split to do that

```
def extract_company(email):
    return email.split('@')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

What this code will be doing, it will be splitting the email address at '@' and then taking the last item and splitting it a '.' and then taking the first list item, which will be your company name.

If you intend to use regex. Then the code will be :-

```
import re
def extract_company(email):
    x= re.findall(r"\@(.*?)\.", "uditvashisht@gmail.com")
    return x[0]
```

What it does is it looks for all the characters between '@' and '.' and then returns the list of that characters. And the element in that list is the company name.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for showing me split(). One of the thing in this assignment is we can't import regex. Also, I think she wanted us to use the find() method. I was wondering if we can use find().find() in this case?

Comment: I think then another answer by @zero will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
def extract_company(email):
    index_of_at = email.find('@')

    return email[index_of_at+1:email.rfind('.')]
```

Assuming you're required to use base Python, this is one way.

1. Store the index where the first '@' is found.
2. slice the string such that you start at the letter *after* '@' (i.e. `index_of_at + 1`) and the last '.'(i.e. `email.rfind('.')`).

Comment: Okay! I think I finally got the right answer. Thank you so much. I didn't really think of storing the index into email[email.find()]. I was just using email.find() and it was difficult to understand how to get from @ to .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt `re` library to extract the company name from the email.

Example:

```
import re
email = "lahre@uber.com"
print(re.findall(r'\w+[.]', email)[0][:-1])
```

Output:

```
uber
```

Comment: Hello, can you explain more on the range [0] [:-1]?

Comment: The `re.findall` method returns a list of values. The `[0]` indicates the first vallue of the `list`. The company name in the list contains `.` as the last character. `[:-1]` is to extract the company name without `.`.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to the first answer, but using index() function by iterating the string with split() function and assigning 2 seperate variables. Slicing operation pin-points towards the string value between "@" and "."

```
def find_companyname():
    name = input("Enter in an email address: ")
    for i in name.split():
        n = i.index("@")   ## Slice begins +1 avoiding the @
        d = i.index(".")   ## Slice end and by default not accounting it
    print(name[n+1:d])
```